# Get HTML inner HTML in C# when element not runat="server"

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I have an HTML span that contains a number.

The span has its value set by some JavaScript, so is not `runat="server"`

I now need to get the value contained in this span, and store it in a C# string.

This is proving more difficult than expected.

I am able to get an alert box that displays this value by doing the following:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "IR", "setTimeout(function(){alert(document.getElementById(\"LoanInterestRate\").innerHTML);}, 3000)", true);
```

But I cannot see how to return this value to the C# code.

I know this is because `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` returns a void, but is there a way of setting the return value for this?

Or is there another way of getting an HTML element.

I know I can use a hidden server side div, but this does not really suit my purposes.

I need a way to obtain the value of the HTML span using C#.

Any ideas, I have been trying for a while and not got anywhere,  and I think this is is a useful thing to do.

Comment: Do you need this value before it get sent to the client or is it ok if client send it back?

Comment: After a second thought, don't you have control of the javascript that set this value? .. is it not from your web server? ... and how does this value gets created in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create a "real" `runat=server` element/control without doing a full postback to the server.

The best approach may be to write some script that stores the `innerHTML` into an ASP.Net hidden field right before you submit the page.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use Sessions or cookies. You can set session value in java script and access it in code behind.

Please  [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/702558/set-session-values-using-javascript) link for example